# inner join that will display all posts of a category when searched in a textbox in laravel

Tags: database, laravel-5, inner-join, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to find a way that when a user fills up a search bar with a category like music or video. Once submitted this will trigger a query. This will output all posts of a particular category. I have tried using inner join to join the 2 tables accessions and categories. I am stuck since this is not working. Please help me.

```js
public function getSearch(Request $request){

        $categories = Category::all();


        $search = $request->input('search'); 
       

        $accessions = DB::table('accessions')
            ->leftJoin('categories', 'accessions.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
            ->where('category_name','=','%'.$search.'%')
            ->get();


        return view('accessions.index')->withAccessions($accessions)->withCategories($categories);


    }
```

```js
//tell relationship that an accession belongs to a category
    
    public function category(){

     return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');

    }
```

```js
//this shows relationship that a category has many accessions
    
    public function accessions(){

     return $this->hasMany('App\Accession');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed the something. Should be categories.category_name

```js
public function getSearch(Request $request) {

  $categories = Category::all();


  $search = $request - > input('search');


  $accessions = DB::table('accessions') - > leftJoin('categories', 'accessions.category_id', '=', 'categories.id') - > where('**categories.category_name**', 'like', '%'.$search.
    '%') - > get();


  return view('accessions.index') - > withAccessions($accessions) - > withCategories($categories);


}
```